# nodejs modules.exports with ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm just learning ES6 coming from ES5 Functions.

Certain things really confuse me:

We have exports For example,

```
function B(){
// Some definition
}

exports.modules = B();
```

**If we are using class based syntax, does that mean we don't need exports at all? (if not, how do we write it?) When do you actually need to use exports? (As opposed to calling constructor by using 'new' keyword?). What's the difference?**

Personal opinion:

ES6 feels like I'm writing Java code in javascript :-\ I love functional programming but looks like ES6 is the way to go (part of me hates the new syntax but other half wants to give it a shot.. anyone been here?)

Please enlighten me.

Comment: "We have exports in ES5." No we don't.

Comment: Are you sure `exports.modules` shouldn't rather be `module.exports`? I'm assuming you're using the CommonJS module system at the moment.

Comment: did you... try? you still have to tell the module what to export.

Comment: I don't see why I was graded -4 for asking a question (or expressing my opinion). I thought SO was a place where I can ask questions or express my thoughts! Oh my!

Comment: You can ask questions and express your thoughts, just don't expect everyone to like your thoughts or the form they are expressed in. I did not downvote, but I did not upvote either, because your question is not clear ("how do we write it" - write what?), is not correct (`exports.modules` is not how exports work), and parts of it do not make sense (what's with bullet and R at the end? It looks like something not finished or formatting error.)

Answer (score 5):

> If we are using class based syntax, does that mean we don't need exports at all?

No. Those two have absolutely nothing to do with each other.

- `class` syntax is about defining constructors and prototype methods.
- `exports` are about making values available to other files (modules), being specific to the environment (node.js) you are using and not to the language.

So even when you switch from `function B` to `class B`, that doesn't change anything about the module system. And if you change from common.js style to ES6 module syntax to export your `B` or `new B()` or whatever, that doesn't change anything about the declaration of `B`.

> ES6 feels like I'm writing Java code in javascript :-\ I love functional programming but looks like ES6 is the way to go.

ES6 `class` syntax is just sugar for constructors and prototypes (making it easier/shorter to read and write). If you're into functional programming and didn't use constructors previously, you won't use them ES6 either.

Answer (score -1):

ES6 modules export immutable bindings
In contrast to CommonJS modules, ES6 modules export bindings, live connections to values. The following code demonstrates how that works:

```
//------ lib.js ------
export let mutableValue = 3;
export function incMutableValue() {
    mutableValue++;
}

//------ main1.js ------
import { mutableValue, incMutableValue } from './lib';

// The imported value is live
console.log(mutableValue); // 3
incMutableValue();
console.log(mutableValue); // 4

// The imported value can’t be changed
mutableValue++; // TypeError
```

If you import the module object via the asterisk (*), you get similar results:

```
//------ main2.js ------
import * as lib from './lib';

// The imported value is live
console.log(lib.mutableValue); // 3
lib.incMutableValue();
console.log(lib.mutableValue); // 4

// The imported value can’t be changed
lib.mutableValue++; // TypeError
```

Take a look at: http://es6-features.org/#ValueExportImport and
 http://www.2ality.com/2015/07/es6-module-exports.html